# Heat equation, initial-boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $u (x, t)$ be a solution of the initial -boundary value problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
U_t  -  U_xx  = 0 & 0 < x < L, t > 0 \\
U (0, t) = U (L, t) = 0 &  t > 0 \\
U (x, 0) = f (x) &  0 < x < L
\end{array}\right.$$
Show that if there is a constant $C$ such that for $t > 0, |U (x, t)|  <= Ce^ {-t^2}$, then $f (x) = 0$ for $0 < x < L$.

Answer (score 0):

We may express $f$ as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sin \left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right).
$$
Then
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{k^2\pi^2 t}{L^2}}\sin \left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right),
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert u(x,t)\rvert \le c\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\pi^2 t}{L^2}}.
$$
If $L=\pi$, then
$$
\lvert u(x,t)\rvert \le c\,\mathrm{e}^{-t}.
$$

Comment: Thanks,  Yiorgos. Could the same or similar results be achieved by using the heat kernel or the fundamental solution?